# Angular dynamic searchbox for table column filtering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a working table code:

I just want to add a dynamic search box to filter this table for the column name domain. While user enters a new character input(it will be searched in column **domain**), the table will be filtered.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="Domain_Data">
          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="15%">Id</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="15%">{{config.id}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="domain">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="50%">Domain</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="50%">{{config.domain}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="disable">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="30%">Disabled</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="30%">{{config.disable}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container cdkColumnDef="button">
            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="15%">Delete</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let config" fxFlex="15%"> <mat-icon (click)="deleteDomain(config)">delete_forever</mat-icon></mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *cdkRowDef="let config; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

My table's dataSource name is Domain_data as you see, i tried to play with it with searchbox code but could not achieved. How can i bind these?

```
 <div ng-controller="charactersCtrl">
          <input ng-model="config.domain" placeholder="Search domain here">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="c in characters | filter : searchText">
              {{ c }}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you using Angularjs or Angular 2 ?

Comment: It is Angular i think because I use typescript for methods. and your answer at below didn't worked for me. it put a simple search box but filtering is not working it is just a textbox without any function. probably my textbox code in the question is wrong.

Comment: `ng-controller="charactersCtrl"` is used in Angularjs, so the code which you were trying to modify for the filter does not work with Angular 2+ . You need to use some column filter for Angular material

Answer (score 0):

search text should be `filter : config.domain`

```
<div ng-controller="charactersCtrl">
      <input ng-model="config.domain" placeholder="Search domain here">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in characters | filter : config.domain">
          {{ c }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```